# How to extract tuples from a table using the projection criteria as month name in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table 'emp' whose schema is defined as(empno, ename,hiredate) ,I am trying to project out the names of all those employees who joined in the moth of January , so for this I wrote the below query but it not printing any records ,It works fine if  I don't use the where clause , else it is not working .

```
select ename from emp where ( to_char(to_date(extract(month from hiredate),'MM'),'MONTH')) like 'JANUARY'​
```

Please guide me where I am making mistake .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unnecessarily too complicated.

Try to run this select:

```
select hiredate,extract(month from hiredate) from emp
```

Then if January is 1 from this select and there arent any mistakes, you can use:

```
select ename from emp where extract(month from hiredate)=1
```

Comment: I want to fetch the name of the month since in further questions ,I have to extract name of employees where month from hiredate start with J

Comment: Then I would suggest to try to use your where clause as a column in the select at I did in my answer. You will see the values it gives without delimiting the results.

Comment: Use LIKE operator and Wildcards characters for months that start with 'J'. 

SELECT * FROM emp WHERE hiredate LIKE 'J%';

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

select ename from emp where ( to_char(to_date(extract(month from hiredate),'MONTH'),'MONTH')) like 'JANUARY'​